# Ruby: Nice text on ^C (ctrl+C) command-line interrupt

Tags: ruby, command-line, interrupt

I am writing a small command-line program in Ruby that looks for changes in a specific folder.

This program repeats a loop every few second to see if there are changes. To stop the program, the user can use Ctrl+C (To send ^C to the console).

Right now, Ruby sends the following stack trace when this happens:

```
^C./filename.rb:64:in `sleep': Interrupt
from ./filename.rb:64:in `block in parse'
from ./filename.rb:62:in `loop'
from ./filename.rb:62:in `parse'
from ./filename.rb:124:in `<main>'
```

I would like to change this to show an  `Exiting now...` message, similar to what programs like Rails show when closed in this way.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doing *ctrl + c* simply sends [`SIGINT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT) signal to the given ruby process. You can intercept it by rescuing `Interrupt`:

```
begin
  loop do
    puts "foo bar baz"
  end
rescue Interrupt
  puts "\nExiting..."
end
```